# Deliverability, sending from a domain that's not authenticated (in the case of a dynamic sender profile)

Tags: marketing-cloud, deliverability, sap

I have a domain such as "mktg.companyname.com" which is the authenticated domain submitted as part of SAP.  The from name would be something like "Company Name".  This is the domain that emails send from.  Now, in the event of a dynamic sender profile, where we can basically override the "From Name" and "From Email" via AMPScript, and we want to put something like "John Doe" as the From Name and "jdoe@companyname.com" as the From Email, this wouldn't have a negative impact on deliverability, would it?  Would the email still technically be sending from "mktg.companyname.com", but the subscriber would just see "John Doe" / "jdoe@companyname.com" in the email address and from name in their inbox?

EDIT:

Can we override the From Email Address to display something like jdoe@gmail.com and it not have any negative impact on deliverability?  Or does it NEED to have the authenticated domain as part of the sender's email address?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Correct, as long as the domain remains the same as your SAP authenticated domain name, there is no extra impact on deliverability you'd need to worry about.

Email is indeed still sent out from the authenticated domain address (*companyname.com*) no matter what is dynamically set in your Sender Address.

Read: [**From Address Management**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_from_address_management.htm&type=5)

> When AMPscript is entered for Use the specified information for Sender
>   Information the Verify button automatically changes to Verified.
>
> However, dynamically generated From Addresses via this functionality
>   are validated at send time and only verified addresses from your data
>   source are sent. Therefore, verify all possible From Addresses ahead
>   of time so they don’t fail at send time. Authenticated domain, such as
>   **Sender Authentication Package or Private Domain, do not need to go
>   through verification.**

For the last question, yes - this is what the subscriber would see, but - some email clients have an option to see where the Email originated from (Gmail for an example)

To be more exact, the `mailed-by` domain and `signed-by` domain are shown.

In case your SAP domain is the same as the domain you use for dynamic sender address, this is not a problem and everything will be matching.

In case you have purchased Private Domain SKU, then you would see the email was mailed by the SAP domain, but signed by the Private Domain domain. It will not have an impact on deliverability or anything as long as the DKIM and SPF are correctly configured.

Comment: Thanks @Rain.  What about if the authenticated domain is "mktg.companyname.com" but you want to override the From Email Address to display "jdoe@gmail.com"?  Would that be an issue?

Comment: Of course, that would be a big no-no. This is what the Nigerian scammers are doing these days, by pretending the Email has been sent from FBI domain, or someone's personal email, like Bill.Gates@outlook.com or something. This causes the Email either be blocked, marked as spam or have a warning label with it saying "this email might not have come from the address it claims". The reason being that the specific domain (gmail for an example) isn't authenticated to send out Emails from your sender IP and also doesn't have the DKIM and SPF set for your SFMC in the domain configuration.